# Is there an API for receipt reading?

Tags: html, mobile, jquery-mobile, computer-vision

I had an idea for my first mobile application and I was thinking of making it in HTML5 + Jquery Mobile.  The core functionality is:

1. to be able to take a picture of a receipt
2. digitize all the information.

I've never made a mobile app before and I'm not sure if this is possible.  If there is no API available, how would I go about rolling my own receipt reader? Thanks!  Please let me know if I am being stupid.

Edit: I found a service that lets me use their application to take a picture(or e-mail the picture) of the receipt and have it extract the necessary information. http://www.proongo.com/b/receipt-reading.php.  I'm not exactly sure how to use this service but I will do more research tomorrow and share with you what I find.

Comment: Presuming you want to actually know what the numbers are on the receipt, you would need some sort of OCR software that could recognize the numbers from the image of the receipt.  Since that is not part of HTML5 or jQuery Mobile, you'd have to find some library that could do that.  Usually, this type of process would be done on a server, not in a browser.

Comment: Thanks, OCR was the keyword I was forgetting and I found something that may be relevant.  It's 4:30 am so I'll go to sleep and do more research tomorrow.  It doesn't really say in what form I'll receive the OCRed information and how much it'll cost to use the service, but i'll try e-mailing them tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an OCR API service with a number of different pay-per business models called [OCRAPISERVICE](http://ocrapiservice.com/).  They have a number of [examples](http://ocrapiservice.com/documentation/) hosted on github using various mobileOSs through PhoneGap. They do have a free-trial model that lets you submit 100 requests.

Comment: Now I just have to figure out how I can parse the raw text into objects the user can interact with.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to apply OCR for software solution with a function of recognizing supermarket receipts. There are many open source OCR solutions like Tesseract and others. However, they are targeted to general OCR. Therefore, you have to use some additional tools for recognizing receipts via a mobile app.

Recently we have worked on the web-based app for receipt recognition. Here you may find some details of the research: http://rnd.azoft.com/applying-ocr-technology-receipt-recognition/

Answer (score 1):

Besides Tesseract, all the big boys: Google, Microsoft and IBM have now got their own offering of OCR APIs. These APIs provide simple image-to-text OCR scan with various degree of accuracy. I find Google Vision to be the most accurate for pictures of a receipt. You would still need to extract the data out of the half-garbage text though.

If you want an API that returns field metadata like: total amount, tax amount, date and merchant information, where you apps can consume directly. Check out https://www.taggun.io. I've built the APIs specifically for this purpose.